# Flash no cursor change onRollOver

Tags: flash, events, cursor, actionscript-2

How to make that after onRollOver event mouse would'nt change. I got movieclip and i want that mouse cursor would be the same after rollover, that some kind of animation would start, but it would not look like that you can press on it.

Comment: A `MovieClip` shouldn't change the cursor on roll over anyway?

Comment: I think they want cursor to change on roll over - I'm unsure if this question is regarding changing on roll over or returning on mouse out.

Comment: Well.. MovieClip change cursor if actionscript use it. My code:

mc.onRollOver = function() {
 mc.gotoAndStop(2);
}

Comment: @MartyWallace was right (of course).  Updated answer, but I'm still slightly unsure about what you're asking.  You mean after the first button press?  Otherwise changing cursor on roll over doesn't make sense as it would change to a hand and immediately back on the same frame.

Comment: Per your comment of AS2, my answer doesn't apply.  Sorry.  I've updated your question with the actionscript-2 tag.

Comment: Note: I've done some revisiting AS2 and indeed if you assign a function to `onRelease` etc, the hand will become a cursor on roll over.

Comment: Cursor will become a hand even :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want for ActionScript 2 is:

```
movieClip.useHandCursor = false;
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry i didn't mention about as2 in start:>